# Return row position with Spring getJdbcTemplate()

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT rank FROM 
    (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, score_id From Model_Score where model_id = ? ORDER BY score_id ) 
AS X JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) 
AS Y where X.score_id = ?
```

I need to get the row of the element that match the condition model and score.

In my java class I'm using this:

```
return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sqlCommand, new Object[] {model_id, score_id}, Integer.class);
```

but it generates a null point exception. Is it possible that the "@rank" token is the main cause?

thanks,
Andrea

-- Stacktrace

```
02:17:38,793 PM CEST ERROR ModelDaoMySql @ getLevelOfRecommendation [456] Unable to getLevelOfRecommendation(model: 10, score_id: 17) - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mediresource.datatype.model.database.mysql.ModelDaoMySql.getLevelOfRecommendation(ModelDaoMySql.java:437)
    at com.mediresource.datatype.question.PEAQFactory.getPeaqModels(PEAQFactory.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.callReflectionGetContent(BOContentFactory.java:888)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.generateWidget(BOContentFactory.java:496)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.fillContent(BOContentFactory.java:458)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.getBOContent(BOContentFactory.java:387)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.getBOContent(BOContentFactory.java:410)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.getBOContent(BOContentFactory.java:410)
    at com.mediresource.container.BOContentFactory.getBOContent(BOContentFactory.java:261)
    at com.mediresource.test.application.ManulifePEAQ.test_PEAQ(ManulifePEAQ.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: I suggest posting your whole stack trace.

Comment: @Mena done but nothing interesting

Comment: What is line 437 of your `ModelDaoMySql`? Don't look like a query problem but a problem of misconfiguration to me.

Comment: @AndreaGirardi what [M. Deinum](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) says.

Comment: is the row of the exception print. Need to fix the log output. I've a lot of other query that works fine in same class

Comment: In my opinion is the @ that generate the issue. Not able to find the documentation but quite sure with @ is expecting a parameter